# Firebase crash reporting confusion

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

This is a confusing step from https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#set_up_crash_reporting

```
Import the Firebase module in your UIApplicationDelegate subclass:
OBJECTIVE-C

@import Firebase;
```

Would someone please add screenshots and demonstrate how to do what and in what file to do it?

Comment: have you created a project already?

Answer (score 1):

**Open project**

Double click on your `projectName.xcodeproj` file, and open the project in [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/):

[image]

**Find file called `AppDelegate.h`**

You should see a panel on the left hand side of the screen. If not, open it from the top corner.

On the left panel, make sure you are the icon on the very left hand side. You should see `AppDelegate.h` there, maybe you need collapse a folder.

[image]

**Import framework to the header file**

Copy

```
@import Firebase;
```

and paste it underneath the first import.

[image]